# RxJava- When should I be concerned with unsubscribing?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java

I want to make sure that I am not creating any memory leaks when I use RxJava. Please let me know if these are the proper ways to handle each case...

***CASE 1***

if I create an `Observable` and a `Subscription` in the same scope, the GC would take care of disposing them right? Do I have to call `unsubscribe()` here?

```
public static void createObservableAndSubscribe() { 
        
        Observable<Integer> source = Observable.just(1,6,3,2,562,4,6);
        
        Subscription sub = source.subscribe(i -> System.out.println(i));
        
        sub.unsubscribe(); //unnecessary I assume? GC should take care of it?
}
```

***CASE 2***

But what about an infinite observable and a temporary subscriber? Say I have a GUI that subscribes to an infinite `Observable`. But when the GUI gets destroyed, do I have to explicitly unsubscribe the `Subscriber`?

```
public void attachSubscriber(Observable<Integer> infiniteObservable) { 
    Subscription sub = infiniteObservable.subscribe(i -> countLabel.setText(i.toString());
    
    //do stuff, have this subscription persist for the life of a GUI
    sub.unsubscribe(); //must I do this when the GUI is destroyed?
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Case 1:**

The source is a synchronous finite Observable so the stream would complete and unsubscribe itself (`SafeSubscriber` is inserted into the call chain by the `subscribe` method and will call `unsubscribe` on termination (error or completion)). Note that being synchronous `sub` won't be assigned till the stream has finished!

**Case 2:**
I recommend you do ensure `unsubscribe` gets called in this case to stop the activity and release its resources. Note that a more flexible pattern that will work with both synchronous and asynchronous sources is to set up the `Subscriber` beforehand and not rely on a return from the `subscribe` method:

```
Subscriber<Integer> subscriber = Subscribers.from(i-> {countLabel.setText(i.toString);});
infiniteObservable.subscribe(subscriber);
```

Now if you call `subscriber.unsubscribe()` from a thread other than the thread on which the observable is subscribed on then it will stop even if the observable was a synchronous source.